# Simple Modal and Javascript Call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a Simply Modal popup dialog which works fine if you click on

```
    <a href='#' class='confirm'>Demo</a>
```

however how can I call this "confirm" css class from within Javascript. I have tried...

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
       $(".confirm").click();
       ** Also tried this to but no good... **
       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = 'confirm';
    </script>
```

But didn't work. I'm sure this is pretty easy to do but can't seem to get it.

Thanks,

Frank G.

***** HERE IS THE SCRIPT I AM USING *********************
         
        
        
         SimpleModal Confirm Modal Dialog

```
    <!-- Page styles -->
    <link type='text/css' href='css/demo.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />

    <!-- Confirm CSS files -->
    <link type='text/css' href='css/confirm.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />


    <!-- JS files are loaded at the bottom of the page -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='container'>
<div id='logo'>
    <h1>Simple<span>Modal</span></h1>
    <span class='title'>A Modal Dialog Framework Plugin for jQuery</span>
</div>
<div id='content'>
    <div id='confirm-dialog'>
        <h3>Confirm Override</h3>
        <p>A modal dialog override of the JavaScript confirm function. Demonstrates the use of the <code>onShow</code> callback as well as how to display a modal dialog confirmation instead of the default JavaScript confirm dialog.</p>
        <input type='button' name='confirm' class='confirm' value='Demo'/> or <a href='#' class='confirm'>Demo</a>
    </div>

    <!-- modal content -->
    <div id='confirm'>
        <div class='header'><span>Confirm 123</span></div>
        <div class='message'></div>
        <div class='buttons'>
            <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- preload the images -->
    <div style='display:none'>
        <img src='img/confirm/header.gif' alt='' />
        <img src='img/confirm/button.gif' alt='' />
    </div>
</div>
    </div>


    <!-- Load JavaScript files -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/confirm.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.confirm').dialog({modal:true});
      $('.confirm').modal();
  $(".confirm").click();

    $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.confirm').dialog({modal:true});
       $('.confirm').modal();
   $(".confirm").click();
     });​

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Surely [the documentation](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) tells you how to open a modal programmatically?

Comment: sidenote: omite the language attrribute on your script tag, thats [deprecated since long time](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

Comment: hint: the method you are looking for starts with `m` and ends with `odal` ;)

Comment: Hello TJ, It does using the link calling a class="confirm" but I need to call this through javascript at the start of the page load. I am creating a reminder window and if I reminder is active then I need to popup the window. Do you know how to call this? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you trying to run that code before the DOM is ready or before you've bound a click handler to it to do the modal stuff? Because in a general sense that is exactly how you programmatically trigger a click as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezs4j/

Comment: @user1227427: I haven't used Simple Modal, I've just glanced at the documentation. Have another read, there's more there than just hooking up on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try this jquery solution:

```
$("style[type=text/css]").text('@import url("*.css");');
```

Comment: @SheikhHeera I am creating a reminder page. I load data from a db and if any bit of that data has a reminder that's past the date then I want to remind the user by popuping the jquery box. So ideally I am going to parse the db then do an if then with javascript and if true then call the jquery box. and that's where i'm having problems.

Answer (score 0):

To call it on page load simply call it inside document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal_div_id').modal(); // Id would be better (#confirm)
});​
```

This will call it at the page load. Make sure you have only one `class` at the page named as `confirm`.

[**Documentation.**](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

[**A fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2SxmE/1/).

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Any other suggestions? Thanks again for your efforts :) Again the script works it's been tested if I click on the hyper link a href='#' class='confirm'>Demo it popups the box.

Comment: If anyone would like to play around with the Simply Modal i'm using here is the link: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

Comment: Hera is an example of calling something in ready event but it's using jquery ui dialog but the logic is same. [Link here](http://jsfiddle.net/5RVSG/).

Comment: Yea but i'm doing what you give me and its not popping up the window. I don't know why any other suggestions. Did you see the script I posted at the top of the page?

Comment: Put you popup call `script` bottom of all other `script` inclusion.

Comment: I just posted the entire document so you can see how its laided out. I didn't included the css but maybe this might help. Please take a moment and look at the very top of the page were it says *** HERE IS MY SCRIPT *** let me know what you think? Again thanks so much for your help!!!!

Comment: You are using `confirm` plugin not `jQuery ui dialog` so use `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.confirm').modal(); });`

Comment: This is what I have now but still doesn't work <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ $('.confirm').modal(); }); 
</script>

Comment: This are the errors that firefox says: Timestamp: 7/11/2012 4:53:58 AM
Error: $ is not defined
Source File: http://192.168.3.4/simplemodal/index.html
Line: 51

Comment: This is line 51 - $(document).ready(function(){ $('.confirm').modal(); });

Comment: Any suggestions as to what I could do now?

Comment: Your jquery is not loaded, check the link of jquery is correct.